# Test Class: Why is assigning a Contact's Account via Id returning an 'Illegal Assignment' error?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

The requirements for Contacts to have an Account associated seem to be a little loose so I was able to get a successful compile and test run, but I wanted to better understand why this code returned an

> 'Illegal Assignment' error:

```
@isTest
public class TestDeDuper {
    static testMethod void testDupes() {
        //Principle #ls: Create recordsd from Scratch

        //creating new Account from Scratch
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'Tryler McCoder Inc';
        insert testAccount;


        //Now trying to create a new Contact
        Contact dupeContact = new Contact();
        dupeContact.LastName = 'Spiderman';
        dupeContact.Email = 'spiderman@gmail.com';
        dupeContact.Account = testAccount.Id;
        insert dupeContact;
    ...
      }
    }
```

That's the main chunk of code that I am concerned with, since the it appears that this snippet:

```
dupeContact.Account = testAccount.Id;
```

Is throwing this error:

> Illegal assignment from Id to Account at line 15 column 9

I double checked that the field label on Contact for the Account lookup is correct, so what about the way this is written would be returning the 'Illegal Assignment' error?

Comment: GPP.... still facing issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dupeContact.Account = testAccount.Id;
```

this should be AccountId field on contact

```
dupeContact.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
```

Comment: thank you, that resolved the issue. I will keep in mind these fields have subtle sub fields that contain the Id string.